# Why is my div able to change its own properties but not a sibling on hover?

Tags: html, css

I am learning web development and for my first project am trying to make a portfolio site. However, I am having issue with the dropdown section for one of my menus. I attached a :hover pseudo-class to my dropdownhover div so it knows when to open the dropdown menu. However, it doesnt seem to be changing the dropdownnav class at all on line 67. I tried switching the psuedo-class to only change  itself and it works fine but when I try to change a sibling class it doesnt work. I am assuming I messed up my combinators?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:ital@1&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #EF2F88;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: #8843F2;
    margin: 0
}

.navlist {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 40%;
    height: 7rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
}

.navlist li {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.navlist li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Source Code Pro;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    top: 2rem;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdownnav {
    background-color: #8843F2;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    height: 8rem;
    opacity: 0;
}

.dropdownlist {
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
}

.dropdownlist li {
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdownlist li a {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.dropdownhover:hover + .dropdownnav {
    opacity: 1;
}

.dropdownhover {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 15rem;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></link>
        <title>Portfolio</title>
    </head>

    <body>
            <!--NAV BAR SECTION-->
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul class="navlist">
                <li id="about">
                    <a href="index.html">About Me</a> 
                </li">
                <li id="projects">
                    <a href="index.html">Projects</a> 

                    <nav class="dropdownnav">
                        <ul class="dropdownlist">
                            <li class="mania">
                                <a href="">Clicking Mania</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="bloopville">
                                <a href="">Bloopville</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>

                    <div class="dropdownhover"></div>
                </li">
                <li id="skills">
                    <a href="index.html">Skills</a> 
                </li">
                <li id="contact">
                    <a href="index.html">Contact</a> 
                </li">
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've got some errors in your markup: `</li">`

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdownhover:hover + .dropdownnav:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This would only activate if you hover on both _at the same time_.

Comment: Can you add an explanation on why this solution and how it actually solves the initial problem?